# Question on proportionality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I have a question on directly proportional and inversely proportional.

When I was first taught these terms, my teacher would say directly proportional is when 1 term increase, the other term would also increase, but it doesn't seem to apply for $y=-kx$, here, if $x$ increases, $y$ decreases. Which is what I learned as inversely proportional.

What are the correct definitions for these terms?

Comment: just adapt the prof definition to the case where the proportional factor is negative

Comment: Here, $y$ is increasing by $-1$

Answer (score 2):

Two variables *x* and *y* are *directly proportional* to each other if $y=kx$ for some *k*, positive or negative. They are *inversely proportional* if $xy=k$ for some *k*, positive or negative.

While some use "inversely proportional" to describe the relation $y=kx$ with *k* negative, this is incorrect; statisticians use the term *negatively correlated*.